# Null Test After Dereferenc error...codesonar

Tags: c, static-analysis

Using codesonar, I'm getting this error message

> Null Test After Dereference

the code is

```
typedef struct {
   uint8_t Wr;       
   uint8_t Packet[5]; 
} INTBUF;

void function ( int channel )
{
    INTBUF *a;
    INTBUF comm[2];

    a = &com[channel];

    if(a->Wr !=1)
    {
         while(a->Packet !=0)    // <- error: "Null Test After Dereference"
         {
             //...
         }
    }
}
```

please let me know what the problem is!

Comment: This *certainly* isn't Java, and you really, really need to put more effort into explaining the scenario, and formatting your code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I agree with Jon . Please do the right tagging.

Comment: Is there possibly a typo `com` vs. `comm`?

Comment: @Kim suppot, Is this still your question? If yes, have a look on the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I hope you understand that variable `Packet` is an array which can contain upto 5 integer values (8 bit of'course).

Now, as I understand your program, in line

```
while(a->Packet !=0)
```

you are trying to check if the value is `NOT EQUAL to 0`, and if it is not, you are trying to do something. If this is the case, you need to check the values individually by using something like

```
while(a->Packet[i] !=0
```

where `i` will start from to and go till 4 (5 values).

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable `comm` (with *2* "m")

```
INTBUF comm[2];
```

Then you use a variable `com` (with only a single "m")

```
a = &com[channel];
```

These are ***not*** the same variable.